# Systemd path PathExists= doesn't work if tracked file is deleted inside Unit=?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services, systemd-unit

I have simple systemd.path `restart.path`:

```
[Unit]
Description=

[Path]
PathExists=/home/ubuntu/restart
Unit=restart.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the triggered `restart.service` service:

```
[Unit]
Description=

[Service]
ExecStartPre=echo PREPARING TO RESTART...
ExecStart=true
ExecStopPost=echo OK
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/restart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The behavior is following:
`touch restart`
`PREPARING TO RESTART...`
`OK`
And indeed, `restart` file disappeared. However if I try to do file creation again:
`touch restart`
Nothing happens...
Then if I do `rm restart` and `touch restart` then `restart.service` is triggered by `restart path`

Documentation about that is very blurry, and I cannot finally understand why is that happening and how to get around - I expect to to run `restart.service` each time `restart` is created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `restart.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=echo PREPARING TO RESTART...
ExecStart=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/restart
```

In other words dont use the `ExecStopPost=` lines and neither the `[Install]` section because you should only enable the `restart.path` unit.

- ⚠️ Make sure to disable the `restart.service` unit **before** making changes like above, otherwise systemd will still think it is enabled without a way to disable it after the change as shown above. (Due to lack of the Install section)